# React Router - Structure NavBar Before Login and after Login

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Can someone help me with structuring the React App with React Router

```
<div>
      <Navbar /> //Navbar should be shown only for '/' and '/login'
      <Route path="/" component={IndexPage} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Footer /> //Footer should be shown only for '/' and '/login'


      <NavbarInside /> //NavbarInside should be shown only for '/dashbaord' and '/settings'
      <Route path="/dashbaord" component={Dashbaord} />
      <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
      <FooterDashboard /> //FooterDashboard should be shown only for '/dashbaord' and '/settings'

      {/* <Route component={NoMatchPage} />Check 404 not working */}
    </div>
```

[image: Edit 404-react-router (forked)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render a couple of root `Route` components into a `Switch` that matches the "grouped" routes you want to render the nested navbars with.

1. The outer `Switch` component ensures only 1 "group" is matched and rendered.
2. The inner `Switch` components ensure only 1 "nested" route is matched and rendered. Pay attention to route order and path specificity, i.e. more specific paths ordered *before* less specific paths.

From your codesandbox:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={["/dashboard", "/settings"]}>
    <NavbarInside />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/dashbaord" component={Dashbaord} />
      <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
    </Switch>
    <FooterDashboard />
  </Route>

  <Route path={["/about", "/"]}>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route path="/" component={IndexPage} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Note: The odd bit may come if you attempt to reintegrate the `NoMatchPage` route/component since "/" is a prefix for all paths it ***will*** be matched and render the `IndexPage` component. You could use the `exact` prop on the root route but then that will preclude any nested paths on "/about".

[image: Edit react-router-structure-navbar-before-login-and-after-login]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your clear explanation, that was really helpful <3

Comment: You saved my day